# Salesforce calculating different formula size in different orgs

Tags: formula-field, configuration

We have a formula field having the following formula

```
IF( IsClosed,
CASE(MOD(Opened_Date__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7),
0 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1),
1 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1),
2 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1),
3 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1),
4 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1),
5 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0),
6 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0),
999 )
+
(FLOOR((Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c)/7)*5-1),

CASE(MOD(Opened_Date__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7),
0 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1),
1 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1),
2 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1),
3 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1),
4 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1),
5 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0),
6 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0),
999)
+
(FLOOR((TODAY() - Opened_Date__c)/7)*5-1)
)
```

This formula works fine in our dev environment but when we push it to our QA env it fails here saying that formula size is more than 5000 chars. In Dev env, its just 3870 chars.

Any idea why Salesforce is calculating the size of same formula differerntly in different orgs ?

Regards,
Avinash

Comment: Please check out the best practices shared on this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324937&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Are `Opened_Date__c` or `Closed_Date__c` formula fields? If so, the size of that formula  is added _every time it is used in this formula_. A difference in one (or both) of those fields between your environments would then explain the difference.

Comment: No. Opened_Date__c / Closed_Date__c are not formula fields :-(.

I'm aware of the best practices but my concern is why SF is calculating size of same formula different in different envs.